# How can I see AWS CloudFormation logs in CloudWatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am not able to view CloudFormation stackset operation logs in the CloudFormation console. Although each stackset operation does have an "Operation ID" Is it possible to see the logs in CloudWatch?  Or some way to turn on logging?

Comment: Did you ever receive a solution, or figure out how to accomplish this Edgar?

Comment: Two different ways (using SSH to EC2 instance or directly within CloudFormation template) are explained here: https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/devops/view-cloudformation-logs-in-the-console/

Answer (score 7):

CloudFormation stack set events/log cannot be viewed using CloudWatch; this is done only through the AWS Cfn console or API.

If using the AWS-CLI try running `aws cloudformation describe-stack-set-operation --stack-set-name xxxxxxx --operation-id xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx` to display details of stack set operation.

NB: You can run the command while the stack set is being created to view events as they're reported.

Comment: where do you find the operation id?

Comment: aws cloudformation describe-stack-events --stack-name stack-name @apoteet

Answer (score 0):

with this script you can collect all events every stack had in a log-stack.txt file

Be sure you are in the right region :) !!!

```
aws cloudformation list-stacks  --output json |jq -r '.StackSummaries.[].StackId' | while read -r stackid ; do aws cloudformation describe-stack-events --stack-name $stackid ; done >>log-stack.txt
```

log-stack.txt file will take time to generate, if you have many stacks and will be big. The good thing is that you could quickly search this file.

Use a search like this grep, you will get 10 line before and after the found string

```
grep -A 10 -B 10 SEARCH_AFER_ME_IN_ALL_LOGS log-stack.txt
```